# Error occured while installing gradle plugin in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, gradle

[An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle/3.8.1.RELEASE/plugins/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.toolingapi_3.8.1.201607290732-RELEASE.jar.
Connection reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHoEw.png)

I have set gradle path in environment variable and java path also. While i am installing gradle plugin in ecliple juno, it gives me above error in image.
How i resolve this?

Comment: Not really the answer you'd hope, but if you use Eclipse Neon and the official Gradle plugin for Eclipse (called BuildShip), things work fine.

Comment: I am using eclipse luna.

Comment: Still, use Eclipse Neon and BuildShip.

Comment: It is resolved now. Actually i am installing gradle plugin from eclipse marketplace and it gives me error. Now i have install it from its download link. It is working fine now.

Comment: It is also working in eclipse juno and luna.